# Using only CSS, can I limit a child to the parent width, without previously fixing the parent's width?

Tags: html, css, width

This is my first question so I'll try my best to get my point across as coherently as I can.

Lets assume something like:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">shot text</div>
    <div id="child2">very long text</div>
</div
```

What I'm asking is is there a way to "link/lock" #child2 width to #child1's width or #parent's so that #child2 never exceeds #child1's width.

Is there anyway, using only CSS, I can force #child2 (or #parent) to have the same width as #child1, without fixing #parent's and #child1's width?

The point is that I want to be able to edit the contents on the fly (like translations) of both #child1 and #child2 but as #child2 will always have more words it will always be wider.

PS: Don't forget, using only CSS, no JavaScript.

Edit: Done a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ricardojcmarques/seckdugj/5/

Basically what I need is the green box to be the same width as the orange box, without giving the orange box (nor the brown) any width. Using the width the browser needed to render it correctly.

Comment: can you create a fiddle as an example to work from?

Comment: Can #child1 have a fixed width?

Comment: @MattWhiteley, First time using fiddle too so here goes nothing: https://jsfiddle.net/ricardojcmarques/seckdugj/5/

Basically what I need the green box to be the same width as the orange box, without giving the orange box any width. Using using the width the browser needed to render it correctly.

Comment: @FuriousD, nop. Cant set any width or I'd have to do it manually for every page/translation.

Comment: You can't do this with CSS alone. You want the parent block to take the width of the smaller of the two child elements.  The CSS layout engine will try to maximize the width of the parent to display as much text as possible within the available row width.  You need some jQuery/JavaScript or else fix the width of the parent container.  Alternatively, if you want to fix the height of the parent, you might be able to use absolutely positioned child elements, but then, you might get scroll bars appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/schwiegler/Wy22s/598/)

A little bit of a hack but it might work.

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="child1">short text that will expand and expand
<div id="child2">very long text that will remain within the confines of child1
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

```
#parent {
position:absolute;
background-color:green;
padding:5px;
padding-bottom:0;
}
#child1 {
position:relative;
background-color:#fff;
}
#child2 {
position:absolute;
border:5px solid green;
border-top:none;
margin-left:-5px;
margin-right:-5px;
}
```

---

```
EDIT
```

Have a look at this one, it's a little closer to yours but I have to modify the list in order to nest `child2`. I don't know if you have a specific style you need to set to the parent div but if you do it will take some more thought.
[Demo2](https://jsfiddle.net/schwiegler/4qe709qu/)

Comment: Uhm, that looks nothing like what I need :| take a look at my original post, I tried making a fiddle and updated it.

Comment: I posted another example above.

Comment: Thanks, the position tip helped me find what I needed. Chose your answer since you were first.

Answer (score 1):

So just Improvised on your suggestion, the key here is to set

```
#parent{
    background: brown;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Heres is a working **[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cguroo/gaxqwdh6/3/)**

Comment: Thanks, I was able to muster something up with the position tip. Sucks that I can't signal both answers as helpful when you both say the same...

Comment: No problem ;)  Still, Happy to help though.